# Why wont my shrinkwrapped meshes (eyes) not rig perfectly?

Tags: rigging, shrinkwrap

I made this character and for the eyes i've uploaded a svg turned that into a mesh and then shrinkwrapped it arround the head and turned that into a mesh again.
Now after I rigged my charackter, some parts of the eyes just wont rig right.
Does anyone know why that could be? :/

I'll add some photos for clarification.

Greetings,

cherrybug

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select this part of your mesh in Edit mode, remove from all vertex groups then assign to the head vertex group?

Comment: i believe it proably has something to do with the topology, cuz when i try to weightpaint it it wont take every verticies with it. Topology of the eyes is a big mess, im guessing thats because the translation from svg to mesh kinda fucked it up?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ive just remodeled my eyes with meshes now, and it worked. I think the topology was just bad. But thanks for the help! :)